# There was an error parsing your JSON-LD

Tags: json

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{ "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "Organization",
  "url" : "http://www.hstechsupport.com",
  "contactPoint" :
   [ { "@type" : "ContactPoint",
      "telephone" : "+1-866-606-2003",
      "contactType" : "Computer Technical Support",
      "contactOption" : "TollFree",
     "areaServed" : "US",
      "availableLanguage" : "English"
      }

      { "@type" : "ContactPoint",
      "telephone" : "+1-866-606-2003",
      "contactType" : "Computer Customer Service",
      "contactOption" : "TollFree",
      "areaServed" : "US",
      "availableLanguage" : "English"
      }

      { "@type" : "ContactPoint",
      "telephone" : "+1-866-606-2003",
      "contactType" : "Computer Customer Support Service",
      "contactOption" : "TollFree",
      "areaServed" : "US",
      "availableLanguage" : "English"
      } ]

    }
</script>
```

See my code and Get me out from there. Help me

Comment: Please edit your output

Answer (score 0):

your json data should be:

```
{ "@context" : "http://schema.org", "@type" : "Organization", "url" : "http://www.hstechsupport.com", "contactPoint" : [
 { "@type" : "ContactPoint", "telephone" : "+1-866-606-2003", "contactType" : "Computer Technical Support", "contactOption" : "TollFree", "areaServed" : "US", "availableLanguage" : "English" } 
,{ "@type" : "ContactPoint", "telephone" : "+1-866-606-2003", "contactType" : "Computer Customer Service", "contactOption" : "TollFree", "areaServed" : "US", "availableLanguage" : "English" }, { "@type" : "ContactPoint", "telephone" : "+1-866-606-2003", "contactType" : "Computer Customer Support Service", "contactOption" : "TollFree", "areaServed" : "US", "availableLanguage" : "English" } ] }
```

you are missing `,`.

you can heck here:http://json.parser.online.fr/